# Ricci curvature in 2 dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, geometric-interpretation

A well known formula for interpreting Ricci curvature is the following (see for example [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature#Direct_geometric_meaning)). Consider the Taylor expansion of the volume form at a point $p$ in normal coordinates $\left(x_i\right)$:
$$  d\mu = 1- \frac{1}{6}\mathrm{Ric}_{ij}x^ix^j + O(|x|^3)d\mu_\text{Euclidean}.$$
In particular, this gives an interpretation for $\mathrm{Ric}_{ii}$ in terms of volume of "infinitesimal cones starting at $p$ in the direction $x_i$".

On the other hand, it is well known that in dimension 2 the Ricci curvature is just
$\mathrm{Ric}=\frac{\mathrm{R}}{2}g$. This means that (in normal coordinates) $\mathrm{Ric}_{11}=\mathrm{Ric}_{22}$.

My question is, how can I reconcile these two points of view? Why do these "infinitesimal cones" behave the same in two dimensions (but not in higher dimensions)?

Comment: I think perhaps you are confusing Ricci curvature and Ricci curvature operator.  On surfaces, scalar curvature, Ricci curvature, and Gaussian curvature are exactly the same (up to a factor of 2 depending on normalisation).

Comment: Yes, this is what I am saying in the third paragraph. I want to understand if this fact can be intuitively justified or even proved by the "volume of cones" interpretation.